# How does Trello Full Text Search work?

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, trello

AFAIK Trello uses MongoDB for persisted data. MongoDB does not support full text search.

And yet Trello's full text search is both **comprehensive** and **very fast**.

How is that? And how does it handle words/phrases that have been *marked down*?

Comment: yeah thanks for that :-P - I also asked @Trello directly on twitter... and as those guys have been known to answer questions on SO before... I kinda was asking them :-)

Answer (score 2):

While Trello's database has millions of documents in it, the actual set of information that a given user cares about (or even has permission to read) is actually quite small.

Because of this, Trello is able to use a relatively naive search mechanism (e.g. using regular expressions and `$where` clauses) and still return results very quickly.

Disclosure: I wrote the search code for Trello.com